# Auto choose app from app dialog

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a way to auto-choose an app from those appearing on a app dialog when I send some action with an implicit intent.The aim is to avoid user interaction.

Regards

Comment: What are your criteria for what you would "auto-choose"? How will the user tell you what the user wants? How will you deal with cases where nothing matches your criteria?

Comment: My criterion is the most appropriate app, but you are right, depending on the action ,there are cases where no apps are proposed. Actually I want to force ACTION_SEND to be executed with gmail client, which always exists, without the user having to click on the client. There must be some way to get the ids of the proposed apps and choose the one you want.

Comment: "which always exists" -- no, it does not. For example, I have it disabled on my phone, as I do not use Gmail. Billions of people do not use Gmail, even among Android users. Also, that app may not be available to all users, particularly those using secondary accounts on Android devices. Please allow the **user** to choose how the **user** wants to send, as it is the **user's** device, the **user's** data, the **user's** battery, the **user's** bandwidth, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get this by:

1. query the available response by [packageManager.queryIntentActivities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)
2. then when you get lists of `ResolveInfo`, you can get the `ActivityInfo` you want -> then get the `packageName`.
3. And now, you can restrict your Intent to a specific app you want.